# How to understand a theano tensor as a matrix and a keras.backend variable?

Tags: python, keras, theano, tensor

If I am using Keras with theano, what is the difference between A and B in this case ?

```
from keras import backend as K
import theano 

A = theano.tensor.matrix()
B =  K.zeros(shape = (d1, d2, d3, d4))
```

where d1-d4 are dimensions for example (1,4,14,14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/theano_backend.py), keras creates this in theano:

```
variable = theano.shared(value=np.zeros(shape),
                         name='somename',
                         strict=False)
variable._keras_shape = value.shape
variable._uses_learning_phase = False
```

It's often better to use keras objects. They've got shapes and other features for keras models.

Comment: okey! So in my custom layer, can I initialize new tensors with  theano.tensor.matrix() and manipulate them without losing the connection between the layers and the backpropagation?                     
In other words, can I use K.variable to manipulate data in my custom layer? The reason I ask is in the link you shared                                                                                   on line 197:, it says a variable created with K.variable() is "not" a keras tensor- how does that impact my learning process during backpropagation?

Comment: Usually, you can (inside custom and lambda layers) use theano functions and everything should be fine.

Comment: This helps. Thank you